# Does Azure Search work against Azure File Storage

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-files

I know that Azure Search works against Azure Bolb storage for document search, but does it work similarly against Azure File Storage service? If yes, how it is different from working against Azure Blob? Is there any limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE May 21, 2018**
Azure Files datasource is now supported in private preview. Please follow onboarding instructions [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/14274261-indexer-for-azure-file-shares).

Answer (score -1):

Azure Search now has a preview for Azure Files. In order to sign up for the Azure Files indexer private preview, you need to fill out [this form](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR4LjgVsFqNxClqxaKNmnHHJUM1g2NjVHUUFCU0daR1UySDU4SjJBODFTRC4u).

Once the team has added you to the preview, you will receive an email with instruction on how to consume the capability.

Comment: This question (and your edit to the accepted answer) [is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389040/should-information-that-confuses-customers-be-removed-from-answers) if you would like to chime in.